# How to build Vapor3 on raspberry pi with docker?

Tags: swift, docker, vapor

I have tried using the install instructions from https://docs.vapor.codes/3.0/install/macos/. But this doesn't seem to work properly.

It works on my PC though. Just not on my raspberry pi

Comment: After a quick search I haven't found any "official" swift image for arm architecture. You may wanna take a look at this [discussion](https://github.com/swiftdocker/docker-swift/issues/56). Can you also provide more info? Did you manage to install docker on your raspberry pi? Have you tried to `pull` and `run` images for arm? For my case with a rpi long time ago, I had trusted the guys from [resin.io](https://hub.docker.com/u/resin/) and used their base images.

Comment: FWIW, I gave up trying to install vapor directly on a Pi. Instead, I create the projects on my mac and then copy them over to the Pi and compile/run them quite happily. Development of the project can continue on the pi without problems.

Comment: @Nick this worked for me. thanks

Comment: @Nick Where are you getting the Swift 4 complier and runtime for the Raspberry Pi from?

Comment: @DavidMonagle, I am using the Ubuntu distribution and originally compiled it from source, which wasn't easy. I've just looked and I see it is listed as available via `apt-get` now, which would make so much easier.

Comment: Nice. Thanks for the info @Nick